# Apache Beam Dataframe Not Working as Expected

Tags: apache-beam, dataflow, data-processing

In the USING DATAFRAMES section of the Apache Beam [documentation](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/dataframes/overview/#differences_from_standard_pandas),
I made a slight modification to the code:

```
from apache_beam.dataframe.io import read_csv

with beam.Pipeline() as p:
  df = p | read_csv("test.csv")
  agg = df[['A', 'B']].groupby('A').sum()
  agg.to_csv('output_dummy')
```

and my test.csv looks like this
[image]

It does not perform the sum operation. The output file looks similar to the input file

Comment: Hi, can you please post the contents of test.csv?

Comment: Its there in the image.. But you could use the following code to generate it. 
import pandas as pd                          
df = {'A' :[1,2,3], 'B':[2,2,1]}                   
df = pd.DataFrame(df)                      
df.to_csv('test.csv')

Comment: Ah sorry silly question. Can you please post the output of the sum operation? Also, what version of apache beam are you using? The Dataframe API is only fully supported from 2.32.0 and above.

Comment: Oh I see. My apache_beam version was 2.30.0 I upgraded it to 2.32.0 but I am getting series of errors: AttributeError: module 'apache_beam' has no attribute 'pipeline' , AttributeError: module 'apache_beam' has no attribute 'dataframe' ,

Comment: restarting kernel helped! Thanks I am closing this

Answer (score 1):

Updating from conversation in comments:

The Apache Beam DataFrame API is supported from versions >= 2.32.0. To use, please update to that version and restart the kernel.